# How to host docker-compose app on Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, docker, express, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I have a very basic web app that I am trying to host on azure app service.

[image]

The only error log I am seeing so far is "stopping site because it failed during startup".

It is a very basic express app.  I was able to get the wordpress tutorial to work, but not sure what I am doing wrong with this app or what is different about it.

- I deployed it from Azure CLI with the config file pointed at the docker-compose.yml.
- I set the multicontainer-config-type to "compose"

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to host the docker-compose app on Azure App Service**.

Follow the below steps to host the **docker-compose** app to **Azure App Service**.

I have developed a source code on my local machine with the below **VM** configurations and returned a docker file to produce the image out of the source code.

**VM Configuration:**

**Ubuntu: 20.04**

**Docker version**: 23.0.1

**Docker Composed version**:1.29.2

[image]

1. I have created a simple **node JS**   `hello world` application.
2. Make sure that expose the application on `Port:8080`, below is my server.js file

   ```
   'use strict';
    const express = require('express');

    const PORT = 8080;  
    const HOST = '0.0.0.0';


    const app = express();  
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {  
    res.send('<h2> style="color: purple"> Welcome to Docker Compose on Azure web app v2.0');  
    });
    app.listen(PORT, HOST);  
    console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
   ```
3. I have used below **Dockerfile** and **docker-compose.yaml**

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:14  
WORKDIR /app  
COPY package*.json ./  
RUN npm install  
Copy . .  
EXPOSE 8080  
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3.8'  
services:  
app:  
build: .  
container_name: testnodewebapp  
restart: always  
ports:  
- '8080:8080'  
volumes:  
- .:/app  
- /app/node_modules
```

This **"build ."** command will be used to find the docker file in the current working directory(**represented by "."**).
the resulting container will be named **"testnodewebapp"** as we have mentioned the container name in **"docker-composed.yaml"** file.

[image]

If the docker file is not in the referenced path in the **docker-compse.yaml** it will throw an error while executing the **docker-composed.yaml** file as below.

[image]

If the file is in the current directory, you are able to execute **docker-composed .yaml** file without any issues as below.

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

4. I have created **Azure Web** app as below.

> Note: Make sure that you select **Docker Compose (Preview)** option while creating the web app.

[image]

5. Created **Azure container Registry** and enabled **Admin** user.

> Note: Make sure that enable **Admin user**

[image]

Push the images to **Azure container Registry** using the below command.

```
docker tag <image-name>:<tag> <acr-login-server>/<image-name>:<tag>  
docker login <acr-login-server>  
docker push <acr-login-server>/<image-name>:<tag>
```

Once you push the images to **ACR**, check the same in the portal.

[image]

Change the **Web app** deployment settings as below.

[image]

Make sure that add **Config file:** in **Azure Web App**.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
     image: acrvijay123.azurecr.io/nodewebapp:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:8080"
     restart: always
```

[image]

Docker compose app successfully running on **App Service**.

[image]

Comment: How did you get the docker compose yml to work with the build command?  The docs and some other posts say that won’t work. That’s also my experience.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=platform-linux#docker-compose-options

Comment: Also is your config file always going to be different than your docker compose yml?

Comment: For the 1st comment: You can check the updated answer as per your comments and 2nd comment  : Based on the configurations of your application, it might be different sometimes and sometimes not. In my case, as **my configuration** file will pull the images from **container registry** and will expose on **port** mentioned.

Comment: Kindly check the updated answer to host docker composed app on Azure App service.